# Bootstrap: Create confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use the simple trick suggested [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/809.cfm) for create a confirm dialog in javascript.

When I click on the anchor the dialog appears, but I can't close it, and the action starts automatically, even is the dialog is not dismiss.

I obtain the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
```

Comment: @karthikr That wouldn't be the case. It's complaining about the `modal` method, not `$`

Comment: Did you include jquery ui?

Comment: Yes, I included jquery-ui

Comment: Make sure both your jQuery and jQueryUI are up to date. Also make sure you are using your .modal() call after jQueryUI has been imported. Finally, make sure your $('#dataConfirmModal') is actually selecting an element.

Comment: `.modal` is ***not*** part of jQueryUI.  It's part of [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).  The title of the linked page is "JavaScript Confirm Modal using **Bootstrap**" :-)

Comment: Exactly @Rocket :) I included Bootstrap too.

Comment: @Joseph82: Did you include Bootstrap before or after jQuery?  Try changing the order of your scripts.

Comment: Someone can tell me the reason of the downvotes???

Comment: What do you get from `console.log($('#dataConfirmModal').modal)`?

Comment: Just the error I have posted

Comment: @Joseph82 please create a fiddle - this chat debugging is becoming lengthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add reference to the twitter bootstrap library

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js

see working sample in http://jsfiddle.net/pcwD9/

```
<a href="delete.cfm" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @Chamika Can I attach a ajax action in order to send a request of delete to my remote database?

Comment: You can add a javascript event for the button and then you can call the ajax function inside that event. see this link to get an idea about customizing the dialog, http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html

Comment: I include the library bootstrap-modal.js (v2.3.1), but, if I try your example in my code I obtain always the same error

Comment: I found the problem: I was including the jquery version 1.8.2